Getting clean logs with Flutter in Android on VSCode
Is there a way of getting clean logs from a Flutter app in Android?
i.e. instead of having

[log] no color
[log] texto en color
I/flutter ( 5447): normal print
D/EGL_emulation( 5447): app_time_stats: avg=3165.60ms min=3165.60ms max=3165.60ms count=1


getting something that just outputs the logs without the [log] prefix

no color
texto en color


how about
You can follow these steps to get clean logs from your Flutter app:
First, run the Flutter app in CLI A using:
flutter run

Then, open another terminal (CLI B) and run:
flutter logs

In CLI B, you will only see the logs generated by your print statements, without the extra system log noise.

Doesn't it outputs the logs with "I/flutter ( 5447): " prefixed?

how about use debugPrint()?? or in CLI
" flutter logs | sed 's/[log] //g' "

And how do you manage to get that output on the DEBUG CONSOLE of VSCode?
